# What is difference between First Name used for Forms and First Name used for Email Only in Oracle Eloqua

Tags: eloqua

[eloqua page- email field merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYXiq.png)

What is difference between First Name used for Forms and First Name used for Email Only in Oracle Eloqua??

Answer (score 0):

These are default field merges provided by Eloqua. The "for Forms" has no default value if blank, so if the user matches an existing cookie but does not currently have a First Name on their corresponding contact record, nothing will prepopulate on the form. You wouldn't want a default value to potentially be set to their contact record if they submit the form without changing the value. Conversely, the "for Email Only" has a default value set, since in most emails you might not have a first name, but you rather have *"Hi Loyal ACME Customer,"* than *"Hi ,"*.